# comparing two different lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of different lengths. Example---

```
E1 = [1.0,1.3,1.69,2.1970,2.8561,.....]
```

and

```
E2 = [1.00,1.04,1.08,1.1249,1.1699,.....]
```

(of course E2 has more number of elements than E1). Now I want to compare E1 list with E2 and find the value closest to each element in E1, like 1.3 in E1 is nearest to 1.1699 in E2 in this example. Similarly I want to do this for all other elements in E1... So that if I form a new list E3 out of E2, that will contain exactly similar number of elements as E1 and values closest to E1 elements.   How can I do this ? Any help is appreciated..

Comment: By closest you mean where the difference is the least? Are the lists sorted?

Comment: This really would benefit from two exact samples of input and an exact sample of the desired output. Helps clear up what you define as "nearest" for others.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid The lists are already sorted. And closest means the difference is least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty version:

```
E3 = [min(E2, key=lambda x: abs(x-i)) for i in E1]
```

For each element in `E1` it finds the minimal element of `E2` according to absolute distance from the `E1` element.

Note that this list will contain duplicates. E.g. for your example, it returns:

```
[1.0, 1.1699, 1.1699, 1.1699, 1.1699]
```

because 1.1699 is closest to all the larger values in `E1`.

---

A linear time, but more complex solution for sorted lists:

```
E3 = []
p2 = 0
for e1 in E1:
    while p2 < len(E2) - 1 and abs(E2[p2] - e1) > abs(E2[p2+1] - e1):
        p2 += 1
    E3.append(E2[p2])
```

Comment: This is better than the version that used `sorted` instead of `min`, but still much slower than necessary to solve the problem. If the inputs are sorted, we can solve the problem in linear time with a single pass over the inputs. If the inputs aren't sorted, we can sort them in linearithmic time and then apply the same algorithm.

Comment: @user2357112, true, this is not particularly efficient.

Comment: Added a linear time version for sorted lists.

Comment: Thanks! But what happens with dictionary instead of lists? can key =lambda be used in dictionary also? If possible how ?

Comment: @user3724647, with a dict you could take either 'keys()' or `values()` depending on which the numbers are and use that list.

Answer (score 3):

Let me introduce you to a most marvelous Python module, `bisect`.

```
import bisect
def find_nearest(refsort, pt):
    loc = bisect.bisect_left(refsort, pt)
    if loc >= len(refsort)-1:
        # Value greater than all elements of refsort
        return refsort[-1]
    d1 = pt - refsort[i]
    d2 = refsort[i+1] - pt
    if d1 < d2:
        return refsort[i]
    else:
        return refsort[i+1]

def replace_with_nearest(ptlist, reflist):
    ''' Replace every point in ptlist with the nearest value from reflist '''
    refsort = sorted(reflist) # omit if you know reflist is sorted
    return [find_nearest(refsort, pt) for pt in ptlist]

E3 = replace_with_nearest(E1, E2)
```

`bisect` uses the classic array bisection technique to find the largest array element smaller than a given input in `O(log n)` time, assuming the array is sorted. We use that to locate the two values which are immediately smaller and larger than each element of `E2`.

This runs in O(n log k) time, where `n` is the length of E2, and `k` is the length of E1 (assuming n > k). Note that E2 doesn't need to be sorted.

Comment: I think you may have mixed up `E1` and `E2`.

Comment: Yes, yes I did. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def closest(num, lst):
   ret = lst[0]
   dist = abs(lst[0]-num)
   for n in lst:
      if abs(n-num) < dist:
         dist = abs(n-num)
         ret = n
   return ret

e1 = [1.0,1.3,1.69,2.1970,2.8561]
e2 = [1.00,1.04,1.08,1.1249,1.1699]
e3 = [closest(n, e2) for n in e1]
print(e3)
```

```
[1.0, 1.1699, 1.1699, 1.1699, 1.1699]
```

Comment: This runs in O(n*m) time (quadratic), which is not especially fast.

Comment: @nneonneo, No argument there. If performance is key, your answer is what I would go for.